# Have there been any known instances of conlang-to-conlang translation?

Tags: translation

This would include a text written in one conlang and translated straight into another (without being translated to a natural language in between) or, even better, a dictionary meant to translate from one conlang to another.

Comment: This seems a little broad to me - there have even been conlangs constructed using other conlangs (and not in the esperanto-ido sense either)

Comment: The question in rather broad. One possible answer is obviously "yes", there are known instances. Invented language translation games are as old as our online communities and are still a common occurrence. The [*Starling Song Relay*](http://www.frathwiki.com/Conlang_Relay_1) is the first known formal online conlang-to-conlang translation game, and probably dates to 1998 or thereabouts on Conlang-L.